# Is there a way to fit and transform a pyspark transformer on more than one column?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I'm using the pyspark framework to compute TF\IDF representation of text data.
This works fine with one column of data (see the attached example)

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, Tokenizer, IDF
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
sql_context = pyspark.SQLContext(pyspark.SparkContext.getOrCreate())
df = sql_context.createDataFrame([
    {'a': 'another line', 'b': ' and some more text'},
    {'a': 'the cat climbedthe tree', 'b': ' the dog ate some meat'}
    ], schema='a string, b string')

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[
    Tokenizer(inputCol='a', outputCol='a_tokens'),
    CountVectorizer(inputCol='a_tokens', outputCol='a_tf'),
    IDF(inputCol='a_tf', outputCol='a_idf'),
])
model = pipeline.fit(df)
df = model.transform(df)
df.show()
```

However, if I have two columns of text that need to be matched things are getting complicated

there are two issues here:

1. The column names are part of the model
2. there's no way to fit a model on more than one data set (like partial_fit in sklearn models)

The only solution I can think of is to transform the data to have a single text column

```
df.selectExpr('a as x',' "a" as col').union(df.selectExpr('b as x',' "b" as col'))
```

process it, and then reshape it back to the original structure

is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Why can't you concatenate both the columns as `concat(a, b) as a` and pass it directly?

Comment: This would be ok for fitting the model, butI need the tf\idf vector of each column separately